# Python 2.7 regex gets version from drupal

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
def GetVersionPlugsThemes(url):
    data = exlib.GetDataFromURL(url)
    regex = "Drupal \s*?([\d.]+),"
    pattern = re.compile(regex,re.MULTILINE)
    result =  re.findall(pattern,data)
    result = list(set(result))
    return result   
print GetVersionPlugsThemes("https://daa.uit.edu.vn/CHANGELOG.txt")
```

Result:

> ['7.14', '7.15', '7.16', '7.17', '7.10', '7.11', '7.12', '7.13', '7.18', '7.19', '7.2', '7.3', '7.0', '6.4', '7.6', '7.7', '7.4', '7.5', '1.0.0', '7.8', '7.9', '6.9', '6.8', '4.0.0', '4.5.7', '4.5.1', '4.7.2', '4.7.3', '4.7.0', '4.7.1', '4.7.6', '4.7.7', '4.7.4', '4.7.5', '4.7.8', '4.7.9', '4.5.5', '4.5.0', '6.7', '4.5.2', '4.5.3', '4.5.4', '4.5.6', '4.6.11', '6.6', '4.5.8', '4.6.10', '6.5', '7.1', '4.3.2', '4.3.0', '4.3.1', '6.3', '6.2', '7.32', '7.33', '7.30', '7.31', '7.36', '7.37', '7.34', '7.35', '7.38', '7.39', '4.1.0', '4.7.10', '4.7.11', '7.29', '7.28', '7.25', '7.24', '7.27', '7.26', '7.21', '7.20', '7.23', '7.22', '2.0.0', '7.50', '5.23', '5.22', '5.21', '5.20', '4.6.4', '3.0.0', '3.0.1', '6.19', '6.18', '6.13', '6.12', '7.41', '7.40', '6.17', '6.16', '6.15', '7.44', '5.12', '5.13', '5.10', '5.11', '5.16', '5.17', '5.14', '5.15', '5.18', '5.19', '5.0', '5.1', '5.2', '5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6', '5.7', '5.8', '5.9', '6.1', '7.43', '7.42', '6.11', '6.10', '6.0', '4.6.9', '4.6.8', '4.6.7', '4.6.6', '4.6.5', '6.14', '4.6.3', '4.6.2', '4.6.1', '4.6.0', '4.4.1', '4.4.0', '4.4.3', '4.4.2', '4.2.0', '6.22', '6.20', '6.21']

How to get latest version -"7.50"? Thanks.

Comment: you must iterate the list

Answer (score 0):

As this is a changelog file, lasted version is always the first match.

```
def GetVersionPlugsThemes(url):
    data = exlib.GetDataFromURL(url)
    regex = "Drupal \s*?([\d.]+),"
    pattern = re.compile(regex,re.MULTILINE)
    iter =  re.finditer(pattern,data)
    return iter.next().group(1)

print GetVersionPlugsThemes("https://daa.uit.edu.vn/CHANGELOG.txt")
```

result:7.50

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `sort` method of the list object to sort the numeric values mapped to integer, and get the last item of the resulting list:

```
t = ['7.14', '7.15', '7.16', '7.17', '7.10', '7.11', '7.12', '7.13', '7.18', '7.19', '7.2', '7.3', '7.0', '6.4', '7.6', '7.7', '7.4', '7.5', '1.0.0', '7.8', '7.9', '6.9', '6.8', '4.0.0', '4.5.7', '4.5.1', '4.7.2', '4.7.3', '4.7.0', '4.7.1', '4.7.6', '4.7.7', '4.7.4', '4.7.5', '4.7.8', '4.7.9', '4.5.5', '4.5.0', '6.7', '4.5.2', '4.5.3', '4.5.4', '4.5.6', '4.6.11', '6.6', '4.5.8', '4.6.10', '6.5', '7.1', '4.3.2', '4.3.0', '4.3.1', '6.3', '6.2', '7.32', '7.33', '7.30', '7.31', '7.36', '7.37', '7.34', '7.35', '7.38', '7.39', '4.1.0', '4.7.10', '4.7.11', '7.29', '7.28', '7.25', '7.24', '7.27', '7.26', '7.21', '7.20', '7.23', '7.22', '2.0.0', '7.50', '5.23', '5.22', '5.21', '5.20', '4.6.4', '3.0.0', '3.0.1', '6.19', '6.18', '6.13', '6.12', '7.41', '7.40', '6.17', '6.16', '6.15', '7.44', '5.12', '5.13', '5.10', '5.11', '5.16', '5.17', '5.14', '5.15', '5.18', '5.19', '5.0', '5.1', '5.2', '5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6', '5.7', '5.8', '5.9', '6.1', '7.43', '7.42', '6.11', '6.10', '6.0', '4.6.9', '4.6.8', '4.6.7', '4.6.6', '4.6.5', '6.14', '4.6.3', '4.6.2', '4.6.1', '4.6.0', '4.4.1', '4.4.0', '4.4.3', '4.4.2', '4.2.0', '6.22', '6.20', '6.21']
t.sort(key=lambda s: map(int, s.split('.')))
print(t[-1])
```

See the [Python **2.7** demo](https://ideone.com/Koo67b)

As an alternative, you can use comprehension inside `sort`:

```
t.sort(key=lambda x: [int(n) for n in x.split(".")])
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/6UUUfK)